# How can I save an excel workbook into a PDF using R?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, file-conversion, openxlsx

I am looking for a way to convert some excel workbooks into PDF files automaically using R.
I have seen people suggesting the RDCOMClient option, but it doesn't work from my company's PC. The problem I am encountering is that my spreadsheets contain tables, plots and images.
Is there a way I can print the entire worksheets and then save them into a pdf file?

I also tried using the loadWorkbook() function to import the files, but I cannot find a way to save them.
I thought about creating a pdf file with the pdf() function but I only managed to save the tables through the grid.table() function.

Does anyone have better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach

```
library(RDCOMClient)
xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
path_Excel_File <- "C:\\...\\excel_File.xlsx"
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File)
xlWbk$ExportAsFixedFormat(Type = 0, FileName = "C:\\...\\pdf_File.pdf")
```

Type = 0 is a PDF, Type = 1 is XPS, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfixedformattype